# Issue with 3rd party __init__ kwarg placement

Tags: python, django

**Background**

I'm attempting to combine (through mixins) 2 third party app form classes, but am getting this error

```
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'
```

This is the MRO for my form class

```
<class 'account.forms.EmailAddForm'>,
<class 'djangular.forms.angular_model.NgModelFormMixin'>,
<class 'djangular.forms.angular_validation.NgFormValidationMixin'>,
<class 'djangular.forms.angular_base.NgFormBaseMixin'>,
<class 'allauth.account.forms.AddEmailForm'>,
<class 'allauth.account.forms.UserForm'>,
<class 'django.forms.forms.Form'>,
<class 'django.forms.forms.NewBase'>,
<class 'django.forms.forms.BaseForm'>,
<type 'object'>
```

These are the signatures for each class's `__init__` method

```
class NgModelFormMixin(NgFormBaseMixin):
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
       ...

class NgFormValidationMixin(NgFormBaseMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ...

class NgFormBaseMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
       ...

class NgFormBaseMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
       ...

class AddEmailForm(UserForm):
    ...

class UserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
       self.user = user
       super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BaseForm(object)
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
             initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
             empty_permitted=False):
        ...
```

**Question**

Is there a way to fix this issue without resorting to monkey patching the `UserForm.__init__` method?

**EDIT**

Sorry, i should have mentioned that i understand what's causing the error - the explicit use of `user=None` in the `UserForm.__init__` method signature. Which is logic contained in a third party app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the function definition messes up the order of the positional arguments. In all sub- and parent classes, `data` is the first positional argument. In `UserForm`, `data` is still the first positional argument, but it is captured by the `user` parameter. If the `user` is also included in the keyword arguments, you get that error.

A simple solution to this is to use only keyword arguments. Then there will be no positional arguments with changing positions that can clash with keyword arguments.

If this is out of your control, you can override the `__init__` method and map all positional arguments to their corresponding keyword arguments.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation, i could see where the error was occuring, but didn't fully understand why. I've updated my question and added the full implemention of 'Userform.__init__'. If i understand your final point/solution correcty, the problem is, `UserForm` is subclassed by `AddEmailForm` (which i also don't have control of), so i'm unable to override it's `__init__` method (unless i'm missing something?). However, i've managed to use your solution to fit another class inbetween `NgFormBaseMixin` and `AddEmailForm`, which maps `data` to the kwargs instead

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you pass the user argument implecilty in ***args** or ****kwargs** arguments in **UserForm.__init__** method.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my post. I understand what's causing the issue, but as it's due to third party code, i'm interested to know if it's possible to fix this without resorting to monkey patching